# Ruby: Turning a CSV list into seperate objects

Tags: ruby, csv, object

I'm new to Ruby and as part of my studies I got a task to convert a CSV file into something I can sort by price and such. However I am having trouble creating a list of objects. I know that I could make object1, object2 and such, but I do not know how to do this automatically.

This is the code I have so far:

```
class Product
  attr_reader :id, :name, :price, :stock
  def initialize(id,name,price,stock)
    @id = id
    @name=name
    @price=price
    @stock=stock
  end
  def readout(variable)
    print product.id
    print "|"
    print product.name
    print "|"
    print product.price
    print "|"
    print product.stock
    puts ""
  end
end


products = []
newproducts= []
File.open("products.csv" , "r") do |f|
 f.each_line do |line|
   products << line
 end
end

puts products

products.each do |product|
  data = product.split(",")
  inbetween = Product.new(data[0].to_s, data[1].to_s, data[2].to_i, data[3].to_i)
  inbetween
  newproducts << inbetween
end

newproducts.sort_by{|x| x.price}

newproducts.each do |product|
print product.id
print "|"
print product.name
print "|"
print product.price
print "|"
print product.stock
puts ""
end
```

Comment: You should look into the FasterCSV gem.  Doing product.split(",") will not handle things like embedded commas.  FasterCSV will handle a wider range of input.  Otherwise I would take a very similar approach to what you're already doing.

Comment: I'm afraid my school wants us to write stuff like this for a start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the easiest thing to do is to create a list and then, when you create each new product, you just push it onto the list. Then you can use `sort_by` to sort the list however you want.

So in your code, you have the array `newproduct`, so just do this:

```
products.each do |product|
  data = product.split(",")
  newproduct.push(Products.new(data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3]))
end
```

If you want to sort by price:

```
newproduct.sort_by{|x| x.price}
```

Comment: How do I turn it into names? Because the output is.

Comment: #<Product:0x1b192059>
#<Product:0xe9ac0f5>
#<Product:0x51f21c50>
#<Product:0x6e20f237>
#<Product:0x34fe315d>
#<Product:0x1c5aebd9>
#<Product:0x1532021a>
#<Product:0x62803d5>
#<Product:0x2d13981b>
#<Product:0x61672bbb>
#<Product:0x3c6833f2>
#<Product:0x5d2a73d9>
#<Product:0xe1bdb58>
#<Product:0x46dd75a4>
#<Product:0x75568654>
#<Product:0x38d30fb>
#<Product:0x2a8ab08f>
#<Product:0x774d921a>
#<Product:0x5b32627>
#<Product:0x348dcd5d>
#<Product:0x49a5af9f>
#<Product:0x1cad157f>
#<Product:0x275e538e>
#<Product:0x21bfa3d3>
#<Product:0x2c9c82f4>
#<Product:0x5759780d>
#<Product:0x32d8ca48>

Comment: Add a `to_s` method to your `Products` class. This controls the representation for an instance of your class when you try to display it with `puts` e.g. `def to_s; "Product: #{@name.nil? ? 'Unnamed' : @name}"; end`

Comment: hmm. I'm not quite sure how to use that. I added it to Product class, but it's still displaying it as before. Sorry. Started ruby a couple weeks ago. And it's my first language.

Comment: Can you update the code in your question to show have you've added the `to_s` method

Comment: Where you've called the method `readout1` you have to call it `to_s` - this is the method for "to string" which Ruby uses when you use `puts` on some object. Then when you do `puts products` you should see Product: *name* for each product.

Answer (score 1):

There are of course many ways to solve the task you have been given and I don't think you are so far from a workable solution. If you just make sure that you actually save the Products class when you create it, you have a list you can work with.

```
newproducts << Product.new(data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3])
```

As you may notice, I made a little adjustment to your syntax. I changed the class Products to Product since it only keeps track of one product. Then I also changed the array name from newproduct to newproducts since that is actually where the different products will be stored.

After that, you have an array object which you can perform your sort_by tasks with.